# How to get a child of categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, parent-child, categories

I'm created new theme and create list in my theme
I want to get child categories in this list
How do this
Thank you

Comment: Please show your efforts. Share code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: This is my code <ul> <li>child categories here </Li></ul>